# Observable returning null value

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs

I have a child module which tries to login checking the role.

```
this.auth.user$.subscribe(u => console.log(u)) // Child returning null
```

Service

```
     private user: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject<User> (null);
      user$: Observable<User> = this.user.asObservable();
async getUser() {
    try {
      const { token, claims, expirationTime } = await (await this.afAuth.currentUser).getIdTokenResult(true);
      const { name, email } = claims;
      const expiry = Date.parse(expirationTime);
      const authDetails = { token, name, email, expiry };
      if (claims.claims && claims.claims.length === 1) {
        const { groupId, role } = claims.claims[0];
        this.user.next({ ...authDetails, groupId, role });
      } else if (claims.claims && claims.claims.length > 1) {
        this.user.next({ ...authDetails, allClaims: claims.claims });
      }
      return this.user;
    } catch (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
```

I have put Service in all the modules as providers

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: It seems in the moment you subscribe value of user is still null. When you use getUser function? How about console.log after that?

Comment: There is a login page where signup function is activated and getUser() is called. And at that point value appears.... Then it loads the child module then subscribe is called. Value comes null. I'm not really familiar with Observables ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding with the below line in  your description

**I have put Service in all the modules as providers**

Things are not working because you are accessing a **new instance of the service** and you need a singloton instance in order to access the value.

Either we do this : -

```
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root',
    })
export class YourService {
}
```

OR
Add a service only in the providers of the **Appmodule** for a **singleton instance**

So,
I will recommend try any of above two methods and things will work for you.

*Remove service for all the modules providers array. and either use  **providedIn**  way or add in the provider of the **AppModule** only.
then you have a singleton instance of service and will get correct value of behavior subject and all other service state.

Answer (score 0):

Your "seed" value is null.

> If you want the last emitted value(s) on subscription, but do not need to supply a seed value, check out ReplaySubject instead!
>   Source: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject

So just use:

```
private user: ReplaySubject<User> = new ReplaySubject<User>(1);
user$: Observable<User> = this.user.asObservable();
....
```

Comment: Now there is no output in console.log in subscribe

Comment: are you calling getUser(). Is it running into one of the two if .. else if paths and calling the next?